# handing over a link into the translation

Tags: internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3

I just upgraded to rails 3 and face a problem handing over a link to a translation:

I used to do this as follows:

```
t('translation_dest', :link => link_path)
```

And in my translations:

```
translation_dest: "blabla {{link}} blabla"
```

In rails 3 the link doesnt show up just {{link}} as text.

Any Ideas are wellcome!
Maechi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{}} is deprecated, try %{link}